# Trueskill save rating to database

Tags: python, mysql

I found a very nice module for Python, know was Trueskill.

http://trueskill.org/

The issue that I am having, is that I do not know how to save the rating to my database, and load it back (I know how to post to mysql and everything). I am given a trueskill object, and I need to convert it to str so I can save it to mysql. I can't json serialize it.

example is

```
player1 = Rating()
print player1
trueskill.Rating(mu=25.000, sigma=8.333)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep only mu and sigma value to save `trueskill.Rating` object intactly.

```
r = trueskill.Rating()
cursor.execute('''
    UPDATE matchmaking
    SET mu = %f AND sigma = %f
    WHERE token = %s
''', (r.mu, r.sigma, token))
```

Don't serialize by Pickle or JSON. They waste your daabase capacity.

Answer (score 0):

trueskill.Rating object support pickle. Use `pickle.dumps` to serialize Rating object. For example:

```
>>> import trueskill
>>> r = trueskill.Rating(mu=25.000, sigma=8.333)
>>> import pickle # or import cPickle as pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(r)
>>> s
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(ctrueskill\nRating\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'tau'\np6\nF0.36002880172809215\nsS'pi'\np7\nF0.014401152069123686\nsb."
```

Using `pickle.loads`, you can deserialize the string back to Rating object:

```
>>> r2 = pickle.loads(s)
>>> r2
trueskill.Rating(mu=25.000, sigma=8.333)
```

Comment: This does not work.

cursor.execute('UPDATE matchmaking set `elo` = %s WHERE `token` = %s', (pickle.dumps(Rating()), y[0] ))

When I load it again, I get the following error

ImportError: No module named copy_reg